# How to stop ggrepel overlapping points using xlim or ylim

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I am really struggling with what is probably a very simple bit of graphing.

with the following code in R for my volcano plot:

```
> vol+geom_label_repel(data = subset(data, color=="Increased"), aes(label=gene))
```

I get the following picture:
[image: volcano plot]

However if I try to limit the labels to the top right quadrant using xlim:

```
vol+geom_label_repel(data = subset(data, color=="Increased"), aes(label=gene), xlim = c())
```

It does not matter what xlim or ylim values I input, nor where in the code it goes, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: xlim
```

Can anyone suggest how I can get ggrepel to put the labels not overlapping the points in the top right quadrant?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bindrcpp_0.2               readr_1.1.1                DESeq2_1.16.1              SummarizedExperiment_1.6.3
 [5] DelayedArray_0.2.7         matrixStats_0.52.2         Biobase_2.36.2             GenomicRanges_1.28.5      
 [9] GenomeInfoDb_1.12.2        IRanges_2.10.3             S4Vectors_0.14.4           BiocGenerics_0.22.0       
[13] ggrepel_0.6.5              dplyr_0.7.3                ggplot2_2.2.1             

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.3.1              tidyr_0.7.1             viridisLite_0.2.0       bit64_0.9-7            
 [5] jsonlite_1.5            splines_3.4.1           Formula_1.2-2           assertthat_0.2.0       
 [9] latticeExtra_0.6-28     blob_1.1.0              cellranger_1.1.0        GenomeInfoDbData_0.99.0
[13] RSQLite_2.0             backports_1.1.0         lattice_0.20-35         glue_1.1.1             
[17] digest_0.6.12           RColorBrewer_1.1-2      XVector_0.16.0          checkmate_1.8.3        
[21] colorspace_1.3-2        htmltools_0.3.6         Matrix_1.2-11           plyr_1.8.4             
[25] XML_3.98-1.9            pkgconfig_2.0.1         genefilter_1.58.1       zlibbioc_1.22.0        
[29] purrr_0.2.3             xtable_1.8-2            scales_0.5.0            BiocParallel_1.10.1    
[33] htmlTable_1.9           tibble_1.3.4            annotate_1.54.0         nnet_7.3-12            
[37] lazyeval_0.2.0          readxl_1.0.0            survival_2.41-3         magrittr_1.5           
[41] memoise_1.1.0           foreign_0.8-69          tools_3.4.1             data.table_1.10.4      
[45] hms_0.3                 stringr_1.2.0           plotly_4.7.1            munsell_0.4.3          
[49] locfit_1.5-9.1          cluster_2.0.6           AnnotationDbi_1.38.2    compiler_3.4.1         
[53] rlang_0.1.2             grid_3.4.1              RCurl_1.95-4.8          htmlwidgets_0.9        
[57] labeling_0.3            bitops_1.0-6            base64enc_0.1-3         gtable_0.2.0           
[61] DBI_0.7                 R6_2.2.2                gridExtra_2.3           knitr_1.17             
[65] bit_1.1-12              bindr_0.1               Hmisc_4.0-3             stringi_1.1.5          
[69] Rcpp_0.12.12            geneplotter_1.54.0      rpart_4.1-11            acepack_1.4.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of the use of `xlim` and `ylim` in `geom_label_repel`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
set.seed(1)
iris2 <- iris[sample(1:nrow(iris), 20),]
ggplot(iris2, aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width)) +
geom_point() + 
geom_label_repel(aes(label=Species), xlim=c(6,8), ylim=c(3.2,4))
```

[image]

Comment: Just a note, and I have seen this with my data and attempts too, the labels in that area now do overlap, which is annoyimg as that is the point of ggrepel. 

Also the labels in my exmaple above, overlap the poimts, which again I thought was the point of ggrepel, to not overlap points or labels?

Comment: I haven't done extensive tests with this type of plot. There's a spring force that pulls the text label toward its data point. I'm guessing that force becomes too strong when you pull the labels so far away from their points. Perhaps I need to make spring force available as a parameter for users who want to weaken it.

Comment: @Marco, is there any update on spring force argument? I would like to be able to put the geom_label_repel in a specific segment of my graph and not have them overlap in that segment

Comment: @reubenmcg for me these parameters help to avoid label overlap: `geom_label_repel(..., max.time = 5, force = 100, force_pull = 1)`. See also [ggrepel docs](https://ggrepel.slowkow.com/articles/examples.html)